# Why can't I send group emails using outlook 2007 anymore?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

Why can't I send group emails using outlook 2007 anymore?  It just stopped working 3 weeks ago and I don't recall changing anything.

Comment: We need a LOT more information here... are you on a home or work network? Are you getting a specific error message? How do you know they aren't sending? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then use the **free** [Send Messages Personally](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesSendPersonally/) add-in. Trusted and works flawless. Just add all your group recipients and send the message using the tool. It will create a separate message for each recipient.